# wordpress error no such file or directory wp-settings.php line 174

Tags: php, wordpress, debugging, error-handling

I have a problem in my website. What I did before this error appears is that I installed two plug-ins and tried to upgrade WordPress to 5.7. I think the problem is regarding the upgrade. I did rename the plugins folders but I’m still facing the same problem.

Warning: require(/home/vol9_8/unaux.com/unaux_ ******** /htdocs/wp-includes/https-detection.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **/home/vol9_8/unaux.com/unaux_ ******** /htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 174**

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required ‘/home/vol9_8/unaux.com/unaux_ ******** /htdocs/wp-includes/https-detection.php’ (include_path=’.:/usr/share/pear/’) in **/home/vol9_8/unaux.com/unaux_ ********* /htdocs/wp-settings.php on line 174**

Comment: Could you check if file `https-detection.php` is present where it is specified in settings? Maybe the file is in another path and you need to update settings.

Comment: I didn't find it

Comment: I found it in another path in htdics/wp-content/upgrade/WordPress-5.7-no-content-ilhITO/WordPress/wp-include. Should I download it and upload it in the other path?

Comment: Well, [it seems](https://wpseek.com/file/wp-includes/https-detection.php/) like it is wordpress file, not a plugin file.So you may try to put it where it should be. But there may be something wrong with your update to 5.7 and maybe another files are outdated also. Perhaps some directories (or files) are not writeable by user from which your wordpress site was updated.

Comment: Is there any solution to get back. I did delete the plugins folders but still and I uploaded the https-detection.php file but I faced another problem so I delete it.

Comment: I strongly advice you to save (download) your wordpress site as is (i.e. by FTP) to keep everything as a backup. You may download latest wordpress [here](https://wordpress.org/download/) and manualy replace all core wordpress files in appropriate places. Note that you should keep wp-settings.php as this file contains your settings (db connection etc.). Also you should keep content in wp-content directory (it contains your uploaded images etc.). There are also some files which are not necessary [after install](https://wpsmackdown.com/delete-unnecessary-wordpress-files/).

Comment: How can I download the files as backup, and how can I download the latest WordPress?

Comment: I'm new to websites and I'm facing these issues

Comment: You can get latest wordpress on https://wordpress.org/latest.zip
You will need to extract (unzip) files before copying to site directories. 
As for how to make backup copy before replacing files - it depends on your access to files. From your question i can ques you have some access to it. But it is worth asking your hosting provider first. Maybe they have automatic backups and can make new one or restore your site from previous backup.

Answer (score 0):

Go to file.
wp-settings.php and delete line 174 and 175

> //require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/https-detection.php';

> //require ABSPATH. WPINC . '/https-migration.php';